# Prevent MVC form submit using Javascript Function

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, form-submit

I have a `upload.ascx` in my project. It will be loaded inside Jquery Popup.

The `upload.ascx` contains `File Upload` control. The File upload control will uploads `.xlsx and .xls` files. I have added `Java script` function to do this validation (To prevent unnecessary files uploaded).

`Onchange of FileUpload` control and `Onclick of Submit button` the same Validation function will be called.

The File Upload Validation Function is working for both calling. If the user clicks submit button the same function is getting called and working fine.

**My Problem is:** In My validation function i have written `return false`. After displaying the alert Message, the Page is getting redirected to some URL (`localhost/Admin/Authorization/AcceptFile.aspx`). `AcceptFile` is my ActionResult name. It should not happen. The Function is returning False. But the Form is getting redirected to Above URL why.?

I have kept debugger in my Action Result that is not getting called if its wrong File(Its correct). If its correct File the Index file will be loaded with Success message(Action result is getting called and working Fine). .

I suspect MVC Form. If wrong file is uploaded the redirection is happening with out calling Action Result this should be stopped.

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("AcceptFile", "Authorization", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
       {%>
```

**My Javascript Function:**

```
function checkfile(sender) {
        var validExts = new Array(".xlsx", ".xls");
        var fileExt = sender.value;
        var strValue = false;
        fileExt = fileExt.substring(fileExt.lastIndexOf('.'));
        if (validExts.indexOf(fileExt) < 0) {
            ShowMessage(-1, "Invalid file selected, valid files are .xlsx and .xls types.");
            strValue = false;
        }
        else {
            strValue = true;
        }
        return strValue;
    }
```

**My upload.ascx Code:**

```
<div>
    <% using (Html.BeginForm("AcceptFile", "Authorization", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
       {%>

          <input type="file" id="fileAuthorization" name="fileAuthorization" onchange="checkfile(this);" />

          <input type="submit" id="btnSave" name="btnSave" value="Upload" onclick="javascript:return checkfile(document.getElementById('fileAuthorization'))" />

    <%} %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My Self i found the Problem.

Yes My suspect is correct. The Problem is

```
onsubmit = "javascript:return checkfile(document.getElementById('fileAuthorization'))"
```

this should be called Like this in Form tag itself:

```
 <% using (Html.BeginForm("AcceptFile", "Authorization", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", onsubmit = "javascript:return checkfile(document.getElementById('fileAuthorization'))" }))
       {%>
```

But Earlier it was called Submit button Onclick

```
<input type="submit" id="btnSave" name="btnSave" value="Upload" onclick="javascript:return checkfile(document.getElementById('fileAuthorization'))" />
```

I have corrected and its getting worked(Validations and File Upload For Submit button Onclick and File Upload control onchange).

But My question is why the `return false` is not working on submit button click? But its working for Fileupload onchange events.

why the redirection was happened.? after changing the same Line to MVC Form its getting worked (redirection is not happening now) why.?

Comment: simply gr8 !! it solved my problem ,,,thanks dude
(remove onclick from input type button and add in onsubmit of @Html.BeginForm)

Comment: Glad to hear its helped...  Its correct i explained that as `Its my earlier code`. :) Thanks dude., :)

Comment: @NimitJoshi You are welcome. Glad this answer helped :)

Answer (score 1):

Change your submit to this:

```
<button type="button" id="btnSave" name="btnSave" onclick="checkfile(document.getElementById('fileAuthorization'))" ></button>
```

And it won't submit the form automatically

When you're ready to submit the form you can do so with javascript in your callback function:

```
document.getElementById('form-id').submit();
```

Comment: yes i have tried this if i change `Submit Button to Button` Entire Form Submit will not happen. In my Action Result i will get file properties as null.Because In MVC My action result i'm using like this `HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files["fileAuthorization"];` The MVC Form Submition is necessary for this Upload get it work.

Comment: Why do you have `javascript:` in the `onclick` attribute? And it's probably better/easier to handle the form's `submit` event instead of just the button's. And it's probably better to handle events with JavaScript instead of inline HTML.

Comment: @lan Please see my above comment

Comment: @RJK You can just do the submit from within your js function if the validation is true.  See my updated answer.  Ian, I was just copying and pasting what he had.  Obviously its better to bind it with js to begin with rather than sticking it in markup, but I was focused on his specific question.

Comment: @ben336 if i use Jquery Submit. `HttpPostedFileBase` will not get the file from the front end (Web Page). It needs the MVC Form Submition. Then only the posted file will be uploaded through the `HttpPostedFileBase`.

Comment: I have already tried with Jquery Ajax and Submit. But `Request.Files.Count is always 0`

Comment: Please have a look on my answer.

Comment: @ben336 Ahh you're right, I must've forgotten that they were using the `javascript:` part originally. Still, it wouldn't be a bad idea to suggest better practices and/or try to fix code; not necessarily go into a lot of detail